# How to create a table in a database on a different server

Tags: sql-server, table

I need to create Table B in database B on SQL Server B by querying Table A in database A on SQL Server A. Table B does not exist in database B. SQL Server A and B are linked. I wonder how could this be done?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. You want to create table B in a database on a different server, but what does it have to do with querying table A? Are you trying to perform a `SELECT INTO`?

Comment: Correct, I meant SELECT INTO. @AaronBertrand

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using `OPENROWSET`.

Connect on SQL Server B;

```
SELECT * 
INTO TABLE_B
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'server=ServerA;uid=Login;pwd=Password;database=Database_A',
'set nocount on  
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;
')
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your linked server has RPC and RPC Out enabled:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<linked server>', @optname=N'rpc', @optvalue=N'true'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'<linked server>', @optname=N'rpc out', @optvalue=N'true'
```

Then use EXEC AT and dynamic SQL:

```
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE [master].dbo.Test (ID INT IDENTITY, CharData VARCHAR(3))') AT [<linked server>]
```

More info can be [found here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1757/dynamic-sql-execution-on-remote-sql-server-using-exec-at/).